# C++ selecting N characters from string

Tags: c++, substring, substr

I have a String. Let it be `string a = "abcde";`.

And I want to select only a few characters (Let me say from 1 to 3).

In python I would do it like `a[1:3]`.
But C++ doesn't allow me to do that. It only allows for example: `a[n]`, not a[n:x].

Is there a way to select `n` characters from string in C++?

Or do I need to do it with `erase()`?

Comment: Use `substr()` in string class.

Comment: [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) does what you need.

Comment: You can use the substring, or you could append each item in the range to an empty string using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/):

```
std::string a = "abcde";
std::string b = a.substr(0, 3);
```

Notice that indexing starts at `0`.

If you want to shorten the string itself, you can indeed use [`erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/):

```
a.erase(3); // removes all characters starting at position 3 (fourth character)
            // until the end of the string
```

Comment: @UP.iaprograms - What do you mean with `str.erasestr.end());`?

Comment: @UP.iaprograms - Ok, you probably meant `str.erase(str.end());`. `str.end()` points to one past str, so you can't use that. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/end/ - _"Returns an iterator pointing to the past-the-end character of the string."_ And it wouldn't erase anything anyway.

Comment: @ Danny_ds thanx. Now, I do `str.end() - 1, it works Like I want.

Comment: @UP.iaprograms - Yes, but you don't even need that. You can just use `str.erase(3)` to start erasing from pos 3 to the end - see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to reassign the object you can write for example

```
std::string a = "abcde";

a = a.substr( 0, 3 );
```

However to select the characters there is no need to change the object itself. Most member functions of class `std::string` accept two parameters: the initial position in a string and the number of characters to process. Also you can use iterators to process selected characters as for example `a.begin()`, `std::next( a.begin(), 3 )`. You can use iterators that specify a range in a string in many standard algorithms.